# Integrating over 3 surfaces of a tetrahedron

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I am supposed to integrate over the surfaces of a tetrahedron to find $\int \int curl(yi+2j)\cdot n{\partial p}$ where ${\partial p}$ is the surface of the tetrahedron bounded in the first octant by $2x+3y+4z=12$ and the triangles in the $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$ planes.

$F = <y,2,0>$

I have 4 vertices  for the tetrahedron:

$V_{1} = (0,0,0)$
$V_{2} = (6,0,0)$
$V_{3} = (0,4,0)$
$V_{4} = (0,0,3)$

I have also parametrized the first curve (from $V_{4}$ to $V_{1}$, which is a counterclockwise orientation)using:

$t(0) = (0,0,3)$ and $t(1) = (6,0,0)$

and:

$r(t) = <6t,0,3-3t>$ and ${\mathrm{d}r} = <6,0,3>$

I was wondering how I would set up the integral to solve for the first curve. Once I get this first one, the others should be straightforward.

Comment: Can you apply the divergence theorem?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped. I just want to give the best answer I can give you.

Comment: We are not allowed to use the divergence theorem

Comment: That's OK.  That is why I provided the direct calculation of the surface integral.  Does that work well for you?

Comment: We are supposed to use Stokes' theorem

Comment: There are 4 faces.  Two faces have zero surface integral due to their unit normal.  One face has an integral value of $-12$, the other $+12$.  The net is zero, which is the result from the divergence theorem.

Comment: Stokes's Theorem applies to open surfaces and a contour that bounds the open surface.  That is not the case here.

Comment: So, if he says to use Stokes' theorem, it wouldn't apply

Comment: Well, you could apply Stokes' to individual faces and realize that the path integrals cancel since they oppose each other.  You will get zero by using that approach also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\nabla \cdot \nabla \times \vec A = 0$.  And use of the divergence theorem shows that the surface integral is $0$.

If you may not use the divergence theorem, then here's how to calculate the surface integral, brute force.

First, note that $\nabla \times (y\hat i+2 \hat j) = -\hat k$.  Now, let's find the $\hat k$-component of the unit normal for each face of the tetrahedron.  There are three parts.

---

**PART 1**:
The surfaces of the $x-z$ and $y-z$ planes have no $\hat k$ component. So, they contribute zero to the surface integral.

---

**PART 2**:
The surface in the $x-y$ plane has a $\hat k$ component $-1$.  The area of the triangular region is $\frac12 (4)(6)=12$.  So, the contribution to the surface integral is $+12$.

---

**PART 3**:
For the region on the plane $2x+3y+4z=12$, the unit normal is $\frac{2\hat i+3\hat j+4\hat k}{\sqrt{29}}$.

The triangular region has sides $\sqrt{45}$, $\sqrt{52}$, and $5$.

Thus, taking the inner product of the unit normal with $-\hat k$ and multiplying by the area of this triangle gives 
$$\begin{align}
& =-\frac{4}{\sqrt{29}} \times \frac12 (5) \sqrt{45-\left(\frac{9}{5}\right)^2} \\
& = -\frac{4}{\sqrt{29}} \times \frac12 (5) \frac{\sqrt{(29)(36)}}{5}  \\
& = -12
\end{align}$$

---

Putting the three parts together, we find that the surface integral is $0+0+12-12=0$.  Which agrees with the result from applying the divergence theorem.